# Android - SurfaceTexture - Video with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, video, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I use a SurfaceTexture to display a video with OpenGL ES 2.0 on a SurfaceView. The OpenGL context used to display the video is linked to the SurfaceView. It works fine, but when I quit the activity while playing the video, and return, the SurfaceView has been destroyed, so I have to recreate a OpenGL context. Doing that, the video can't play anymore.

```
surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
```

This will raise an IllegalStateException, since its called on a new context, I guess ? I also see this in the logs just before :

```
E/GLConsumer: [unnamed-13710-14] checkAndUpdateEglState: invalid current EGLContext
```

The doc says I can use

```
surfaceTexture.detachFromGLContext();
```

before destroying the opengl context. And then :

```
surfaceTexture.attachToGLContext(mTextureID);
```

To attach it to a new context (on the new context thread)
However, if I'm doing this, I have this error :

```
attachToContext: GLConsumer is already attached to a context
```

But it was destroyed..

So my question is, is there any way to continue the video where it was ? Or is my only option to restart the video ?

Thanks in advance !